# Reshaping an appended list in Python - splitting lists into columns

Tags: python, list, reshape

I would like to change the below list into a 2d array. Lists/Array shapes often confuse me, I want the data into the format such the y=14.96,22.17,... and x=15.25,25.36,... final_array = [x,y], then it will be more easy to plot.

```
[[14.96786030991488, 15.26],
 [22.170739257927302, 25.366999999999997],
 [32.07129009546086, 39.536000000000001],
 [53.91092877753442, 59.655000000000001],
 [90.1398030963187, 89.387],
 [117.33864311518501, 119.70999999999999],
 [123.99886910884739, 155.13999999999999],
 [220.35978335270883, 241.97],
 [246.1408069941774, 281.25],
 [275.5098457739598, 312.33999999999997],
 [326.2608566528128, 365.13],
 [399.24680126783164, 415.20999999999998]]
```

tried this so far:

```
np.reshape(mean_plain,[12,2])
```

Comment: here's how I created it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098768/array-summation-calculating-mean-of

Comment: something like `[[item[0] for item in my_list], [item[1] for item in my_list]]`?

Comment: or actually simply `zip(*my_list)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to transpose your original lists of lists mapping the tuples to list:

```
 l = list(map(list,zip(*l)))
```

If you are using numpy just create an array:

```
l =  np.array(list(map(list,zip(*l))))
```

The shape you want is `2, 12` which is exactly what calling array on the zipped list will give you.